# Intellij HTML editor: how to escape brackets < and >?

Tags: intellij-idea, escaping, html-editor

Intellij HTML editor: how to escape brackets < and >?  For example,

HTML editor:

```
<foo>
   <bar>
       <baz />
   </bar>
</foo>
```

Is there a command to change all `< to &lt; and > to &gt;` in the selected area?

Comment: take a look at this plugin right here https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/2162-string-manipulation

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't simple Replace (Ctrl+R) will solve this problem?
Replace all < with &lt for example.
Maybe use a macro to automate it.

Comment: As i suggested before, you can assign a shortcut to this macro.
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-macros-in-the-editor.html#

Answer (score 0):

There is **Edit > Encode XML/HTML Special Characters** action, but it does nothing for selected HTML code, [WEB-28620](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-28620). As a workaround, I'd suggest giving [String Manipulation](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/2162-string-manipulation) plugin a try